# MVC-EF Reverse Engineer Code first include another table

Tags: entity-framework, include, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5, reverse-engineering

I have an MVC-EF Reverse Engineer Code first model, and want to include another table using a property.

```
 public virtual OtherTableModel OtherTableModel{ get; set; }
```

However when I do this, I get the error:

Apparently if there is an edmx there is an easy way to do this.  In this case, both tables have the exact same primary key:

```
string id {get; set}
```

How can I get the include command to work?

In my controller the code is:

```
ourList = db.Table1.Include(t => t.OtherTableModel)
```

The error I get is:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in      
EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A specified Include path is not valid. The 
EntityType Solution1.Models.User' does not declare a navigation property 
with the name 'OtherTableModel'.
```

NOTE:  I have researched this error but none of the answers I found is geared toward the reverse-engineer code first approach.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the relationship in Table1. EF can determine the relationship if you name it [table] + Id:

```
public string OtherTableId {get; set;}
public OtherTableModel OtherTableModel {get; set;}
```

or you can add annotations:

```
[ForeignKey("Id")]    
public OtherTableModel OtherTableModel {get; set;}
```

or you could use the fluent API that I prefer:

```
public class Table1Configuration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Table1>
{
    public Table1Configuration()
    {
        HasRequired(p => p.OtherTableModel)
            .WithMany(p => p.Table1s)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.Id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Steve.  I checked the annotation method -- [ForeignKey("Id")] .  It works and runs, but many of the results for OtherTableModel are null when in SQL they shouldn't be;  unfortunately in the SQL table although both tables use the same key with the same string length, they do not have an official foreign key relationship.... hence if I use a stored proc to retrieve the other table data, it works, but the include returns some, but not all of the data rows (which I really don't understand at all, I'd think it would always work or always fail).  Does Anyone have any insight?

Comment: Please see related question about these null returns here:     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636437/mvc-ef-reverse-engineer-code-first-include-another-table-returns-nulls-when-ther